Problems with my query in the json validator
[
{
   $addFields: {
      Larva: { $toInt: "$Larva" },
      Ninfa: { $toInt: "$Ninfa" },
      Pupa: { $toInt: "$Pupa" },
   }
},
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "",
            "Huevo": {$sum: "$Huevo"},
            "Larva": { $sum: "$Larva" },
            "Ninfa": { $sum: "$Ninfa" },
            "Pupa": { $sum: "$Pupa" }
        },
}
]

I am using a validator and it shows an error and I do not know why.
Capture: https://prnt.sc/8QE8m_fFLWD1
I tried this query in my terminal and it works, but I check it in a json validator and it shows me an error

MongoDB query itself is not strictly json. One of the obvious examples would be date usages. So it is possible and sensible if it does not pass a json validator but is still executable without issue.

JSON requires the field names be strings. So, enclose them in quotes (for example, "$addFields")  and it should pass thru a JSON Validator. Try using this for formatting and validating your pipeline and see the resulting JSON: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/
